# Always display decimal at the end of the integer in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a requirement where i always need to display the number with the decimal point.
The datatype of the db column is that of number.

If the value is 1.25 it gets displayed as 1.25
But if the value is 1 it does gets displayed as 1 and I need to display the value as 1.00.

I need to perform `rpad` (right padding) operations once I get the result in the decimal format.
Without the decimal, the value of a whole number would be different from what is present in the database.

Example:

```
SELECT RPAD(ROUND(12,2), 5 ,0) AS test
  FROM DUAL;
```

results in 12000 whereas I am expecting it to be 12.00.

Any pointers on this would help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use an appropriate `to_char` call.  Something like

```
SELECT to_char( <<your number>>, '0.00' )
  FROM dual;
```

That will return the string "1.00" when you pass in a value of 1.  If you pass in a value of 0, it will return the string "0.00".  If you pass in a a value of 1.25, it will return the string "1.25".

Answer (score 1):

Try using a number format along with the TO_CHAR function, as:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(12, 99.99) AS test
FROM DUAL;
```

**Reference**:

You can find documentatation related to other ways to format numbers [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34570).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select TRIM(to_char(100.5, '99999999.00')) FROM DUAL
```

The format specifications are here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34570